# A basic result about a bijection from $\{1, 2, 3,\dots \}$ over a finite set $A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm struggling to understand a certain step in a proof of the proposition given above. Here, $I_n = \{1, 2,\dots, n\}$.

> Theorem. Let $A\subseteq I_n$. If there exists a bijection $f:I_n\to A$, then $A = I_n$.

The proof starts as follows, I'll cut it at the part I'm stuck:

> Proof: We procede by induction on $n$. The result is clear for $n = 1$. Let's suppose it's valid for a certain $n$ and consider a bijection $f:I_{n+1}\to A$. Let $a = f(n+1)$. The restriction of $f$ to $I_n$ gives us a bijection $f':I_n\to A\setminus\{a\}$. If we have $A\setminus\{a\}\subseteq I_n$, then by induction hypothesis we have $A\setminus\{a\} = I_n$, **from where** $a = n+1$ [...]

I can't understand why we can conclude $a = n+1$. Why couldn't it be any number greater than $n$?

Comment: $a$ is an element of $I_{n + 1}$ and is not $1, 2, \dots, n$.

Comment: $I_{n+1}$ only has one element greater than n: n+1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $A \subseteq I_{n+1}$. Hence it cannot be other number that is greater than $n$.